# Error in xml_nodeset(NextMethod()) : Expecting an external pointer: [type=NULL] when scraping with RVEST

Tags: r, rvest

i am having a problem when trying to scrape some data, i have created a function that is properly working, problems occurs when i run this function for many different code.

```
require ("rvest")
library("dplyr")


getFin = function(ticker)
{
  url= paste0("https://it.finance.yahoo.com/quote/",ticker,
             "/key-statistics?p=",ticker)

  a <- read_html(url)
  tbl= a %>% html_nodes("section") %>% html_nodes("div")%>% html_nodes("table")

  misureval     = tbl %>% .[1] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  prezzistorici = tbl %>% .[2] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  titolistat    = tbl %>% .[3] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  dividendi     = tbl %>% .[4] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  annofiscale   = tbl %>% .[5] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  redditivita   = tbl %>% .[6] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  gestione      = tbl %>% .[7] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  contoeco      = tbl %>% .[8] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  bilancio      = tbl %>% .[9] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  flussi        = tbl %>% .[10] %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()
  
  info1 = rbind(ticker, misureval, prezzistorici, titolistat, dividendi, annofiscale, redditivita, gestione, contoeco, bilancio, flussi)
}
```

What i am trying to do is to use

`finale <- lapply(codici, getFin)`

where `codici` is linked to many different Ticker which will be used in the function to generate one url at time and scrape data.
I have tried with 50 ticker and the function works properly, however when i increase the number i get this error:

> Error in xml_nodeset(NextMethod()) :  Expecting an external pointer:
> [type=NULL].

i don't know if this may be related to the number of request or something other. i have also tested a non existing ticker and the function still works, problems just arises when the number is large.

Comment: Does it fail at the same ticker even if ticker order changed?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem, i just need to add Sys.sleep in order to reduce the frequency of requests.
the best number in this case is 3, so Sys.sleep(3) at the end of the for cycle.